# Why am I Stuck in a Loop?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

*I edited the question to be precise with what I am asking, and to clearly show my mistake. This question has been answered.*

Why am I stuck in an endless loop? I have tried a few different techniques, such as introducing a break statement in an if statement, and even just throwing a break statement in there. However I am still stuck in the loop.

```
    while (recalculate = 1){

        cout << "\nEnter in the radius of the sphere: ";
        cin >> radius;
        cout << "\nEnter in the weight of the sphere: ";
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "\n";

        if (bForce > weight)
        {
            cout << "\nEgads, it floats!\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "\nIt sunk...\n";
        }

        cout << "\nRecalculate? (1 = yes, 0 = exit)\n";
        cin >> recalculate;
        // See what recalculate really is. 
        cout << "\n" << recalculate;

    }
```

Comment: Because you are asigning the variable `recalculate = 1` change to `recalculate == 1`

Comment: **Turn on your compiler warnings!!!!**

Comment: This has been answered already. I edited the question so that it wasn't a hot mess. I do have compiler warnings on, but this was a logical error. The while loop continued to assign my variable to 1, instead of comparing it, and continued to loop through over and over again no matter what.

Answer (score 6):

`while(recalculate=1)` is always evaluated to true, as 1 is assigned to `recalculate` and any numerical value different from zero is implicitly converted to a boolean `true`. To test for equality, use `==`, i.e.

`while(recalculate == 1)`

Comment: Ugh, I forgot all about that. Thank you so much. That was exactly my problem.

Comment: @Zachary try to enable all compiler warnings whenever you build your code. For example, compiling with `g++ -Wall` gives you: `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]` And **do not** ignore the warnings unless you are really sure that they are harmless (which they seldom are)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `=` is an assignment, not a comparison:

```
if (recalculate = 0) {
```

The above sets `recalculate` to zero, and then evaluates it as a boolean expression. Being zero, it always evaluates to false, and so the body of the `if` is never executed.

The correct way to write a comparison is `==`:

```
if (recalculate == 0) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot that comparison operator is ==